# Как прочитать res.locals.user из node.js в клиенте, который использует одностраничное приложение angularjs

Tags: node.js, angularjs

Пожалуйста, помогите разобраться. Как правильно прочитать `user` в клиенте, который использует одностраничное приложение angularjs, переданный из node.js с помощью `res.locals.user`

loadUser.js:

```
var User = require('../models/user').User;

module.exports = function (req, res, next) {
req.user = res.locals.user = null;
if (!req.session.user) return next();

User.findById(req.session.user, function(err, user){
    if(err) return next(err);

    req.user = res.locals.user = user;
    next();
});
}
```

app.js:

```
app.use(require('../middleware/loadUser'));
```

Подскажите, как теперь `user` прочитать в клиенте?

Answer (score 0):

Объект `res.locals` создаётся Експресом для того, чтобы спихивать в него все данные, которые потом должны оказаться на генерируемой странице. Соответственно, если на отдаваемой клиенту странице где-нибудь напейсать что-то пипа `div(id='user', style='display:none') #{user.name}`, то имя юзера окажется невидимым образом помещено на странице, откуда его можно запросто прочейтать методом `document.getElementById('user').innerHTML`.

В связи с комментариями резюмирую общий принцип: объект `res.locals` существует для метода `res.render` (sic!).

Comment: в app.js передаю
    app.get('/', function(req, res) { 
      res.sendfile('public/index.html');
    });

в `index.html` как в `div` прочитать `user`?
`jade` , чтобы записать `div(id='user', style='display:none') #{user.name}` не использую

Извините, наверное глупые вопросы, но я уже замучилась с этим юзером)
Если не сложно, приведите простой пример, как в html файле увидеть `user`

Comment: А не надо делать `res.sendfile('public/index.html');`, а надо честно переделать этот index.html в любом из шаблонизаторов и сделать `res.render`. Чисто теоретически я пробовал прикрутить этот бессмысленный Angular к файлу jade - и оно работает нормально. (к сожалению, я так и не смог себе объяснить, зачем эта ангулярная головная боль может быть нужна, хотя, может она PHP-шникам нравится).

Comment: Между прочим, в энторнетах есть ресурсики, которые автоматом - сюда вставил это, отсюда забрал то - переделывают html в jade или ещё там во что.